# Masonry in Polymer 1.0

Tags: html, css, layout, polymer

So I have a custom element called `my-element` and within that element I have a repeating template that displays a bunch of custom elements called `my-card`. So I was using `inline-block` to divide the cards in two columns and that worked but since the cards were of different heights there was some ugly white space in between. As per a suggestion from user here on stackoverflow I used column-count to make it work. Visually, it worked but the `my-card`s on the right column are not interactive.

[image: Weird rendering]

If I hover under the first column, I can click the `my-card`s that are supposed to be in the second column.
Despite it not showing in the image above, the `my-card`s will be of different heights so I need to have a masonry layout. One column in mobile screen width and two columns in tablet+. How can I achieve that?

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/NFv6ed2T

Comment: Can you provide code example? I'm confused as to why not use the flex-layout system?

Comment: @Brandon Here's the code for the element. And I wasn't sure I could use `iron-flex-layout` in this case. Can you give me a small example how I can achieve a masonry layout with it?

Comment: Did the code link not make it in?

Comment: @Brandon Shoot. Sorry about that. http://pastebin.com/vYDjMRjt

In the question I had given them generic names but in the code above, `my-learn` is `my-element` and the `paper-button`s are `my-card`s

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any repeats or anything, but why not change your code to use horizonal and vertical layouts? Remove all excess styling except for that.

And the `<section>` tag probably isn't necessary.
Assuming you include the iron-flex-layout code somewhere...
working code w/simple styling: http://jsbin.com/cetece/1/edit?html,output

```
<template id="app" is="dom-bind">
  <paper-material class="card">
  <div class="vertical layout">
    <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="loans">Student Loans</paper-button>
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="wage">Minimum Wage</paper-button>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="racism">Racism</paper-button>
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="climate">Climate Change</paper-button>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="privacy">Internet Privacy</paper-button>
        <div class="button" >&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </paper-material>
</template>
```

This is an example if you need to have the buttons wrap into one row if the container is too small for 2 rows: http://jsbin.com/cetece/2/edit?html,output

Add wrap class to the rows and adjust the styles for a fixed button size and non-fixed wrapping container.

```
<template id="app" is="dom-bind">
  <paper-material class="card">
  <div class="vertical layout">
    <div class="horizontal layout row wrap">
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="loans">Student Loans</paper-button>
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="wage">Minimum Wage</paper-button>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal layout row wrap">
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="racism">Racism</paper-button>
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="climate">Climate Change</paper-button>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal layout row wrap">
        <paper-button raised class="button" data-dialog="privacy">Internet Privacy</paper-button>
        <div class="button" >&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </paper-material>
</template>
```

If you need the buttons to go be able to all align horizontally if needed then simply remove all of the row containers, and the vertical layout container, and place all paper-buttons in one single container, such as the paper-material.

Comment: That keeps it in two columns regardless of screen width. I want it to change to one when its viewed on portrait tablet or phone. Here's the template repeater code: http://pastebin.com/NFv6ed2T

Comment: If you don't set a fixed width to the container, the buttons will fill the container width. If you set fixed button widths and the container is too small to fit them, they should wrap.